# How to show/hide few methods to one client and few other methods to another client in Web Api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web Api say "Calculator". It has say methods Add,Subtract,Multiply,Divide. I wanted to make sure that only Add, Subtract methods will be visible to client when we handover them. And when I handover to another client I wanted to show only Multiply and Divide methods. Is it possible in Web Api 2.0?

Comment: Elaborate on what "handover" means? Do you mean give access to the API? That is done with authorization which is well documented.

Comment: Suppose say, I given the api to multiple clients  which contains four methods, but I wanted to make sure that two methods are visible to client1. Client1 should see only two methods when they browse the web api. Similarly, another two methods to client2 only.

Answer (score 5):

[Authentication And Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)

This article explains it pretty well. Once a client is authenticated you may authorize them to do specific actions based on conditions.

Here's a small example of how authorization works, from the article:

```
// Restrict by user:
[Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
}

// Restrict by role:
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
}
```